# Remove .has-dropdown arrow from foundation.css

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to remove the arrow that shows that there is a dropdown.

I have found this:

```
.top-bar-section .has-dropdown > a:after {
content: "";
display: block;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border: inset 5px;
border-color: transparent transparent transparent rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
border-left-style: solid;
margin-right: 15px;
margin-top: -4.5px;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
right: 0; }
```

and I have replaced it with this:

```
.top-bar ul > li.has-dropdown a:after { 
  content: "";
  display: none;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border:0;
  border-color: none;
  border-left-style: none;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Yet there is space after "About us". Any ideas how to remove it?

[image]

Here is some HTML:

```
<section class="top-bar-section">
    <ul  class="right">
        <li><a href="#">Link #1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link #2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link #3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link #4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link #5</a></li>
        <li class="has-dropdown">
            <a href="#">About us</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                 <li><a class="first-el" href="#">About the company</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">ToS</a></li>
                 <li><a class="last-el" href="#">Privacy</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: You need to show some html code

Comment: Also which version of foundation are you using? Foundation 4 doesn't have a .has-dropdown class anymore.

Comment: I have editted the question. I'm using `foundation-4.3.2`. Also this is my first attempt to make responsive designs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the `has-dropdown` class in your CSS.

It seems likely that it has some additional padding to allow for the addition of the arrow.

Comment: `.top-bar-section .has-dropdown > a { /* padding-right: 35px !important;*/ }` did the trick. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 11):

If you're using Foundation 4 (with sass, which is very much reccomended), you can remove the arrows by changing a setting in `_settings.scss`.
It's this one:

`$topbar-arrows: true; //Set false to remove the triangle icon from the menu item`

Unfortunately, this also removes the arrows on the sublevel...

Answer (score 7):

Argh finally figured this out after an hour

```
.top-bar-section .has-dropdown > a:after {
   border-color: transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

This will make the arrow disappear.

Answer (score 1):

If you're hacking it with just css, this will remove the arrow and the padding on the right.

.top-bar-section .has-dropdown > a {padding-right: 15px !important;}
.top-bar-section .has-dropdown > a:after {border-color: transparent transparent transparent;}

Answer (score 1):

to remove it:

```
.top-bar-section .has-dropdown > a:after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border: inset 5px;
      border-color: transparent transparent transparent;    
      border-left-style: solid;
      margin-right: 15px;
      margin-top: -4.5px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      right: 0; }
```

but to keep it for mobile nav

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 40em) {

.top-bar-section .has-dropdown > a:after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border: inset 5px;
      border-color: #dddddd transparent transparent transparent;    
      border-left-style: solid;
      margin-right: 15px;
      margin-top: -4.5px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      right: 0; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

We may edit the caret-like icon, which is really a border:

```
.has-dropdown > a:after {border-top-color: red !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well for me I just set display: none; to whole ::after element, then just adjusted padding

```
.top-bar-section .has-dropdown > a::after {
    display: none;
}
.top-bar-section .has-dropdown>a {
    padding-right:0.9375rem !important
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can just set display none, or just set the border to 0px. Either will do it for you.

```
.top-bar-section > li> a:after {
    display: none;
}
```

or

```
.top-bar-section > li> a:after {
    border: 0px;
}
```

and then as [Alex said](http://Alex%20Reds) you will want to change the padding of your menu elements, but this is optional.